# What is the difference between "Class.forName()" and "Class.forName().newInstance()"?

Tags: java, class, object, instantiation

What is the difference between `Class.forName()` and `Class.forName().newInstance()`?

I do not understand the significant difference (I have read something about them!). Could you please help me?

Answer (score 266, accepted):

Maybe an example demonstrating how both methods are used will help you to understand things better. So, consider the following class:

```
package test;

public class Demo {

    public Demo() {
        System.out.println("Hi!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class clazz = Class.forName("test.Demo");
        Demo demo = (Demo) clazz.newInstance();
    }
}
```

As explained in its javadoc, calling [`Class.forName(String)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) *returns the `Class` object associated with the class or interface with the given string name* i.e. it returns `test.Demo.class` which is affected to the `clazz` variable of type `Class`.

Then, calling [`clazz.newInstance()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29) *creates a new instance of the class represented by this `Class`  object. The class is instantiated as if by a `new` expression with an empty argument list.* In other words, this is here actually equivalent to a `new Demo()` and returns a new instance of `Demo`.

And running this `Demo` class thus prints the following output:

```
Hi!
```

The big difference with the traditional `new` is that `newInstance` allows to instantiate a class that you don't know until runtime, making your code more dynamic.

A typical example is the JDBC API which loads, at runtime, the exact driver required to perform the work. EJBs containers, Servlet containers are other good examples: they use dynamic runtime loading to load and create components they don't know anything before the runtime.

Actually, if you want to go further, have a look at Ted Neward paper [Understanding Class.forName()](https://www.theserverside.com/news/1365412/Understanding-ClassforName-Java) that I was paraphrasing in the paragraph just above.

**EDIT** (answering a question from the OP posted as comment): The case of JDBC drivers is a bit special. As explained in the [DriverManager](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/drivermanager.html) chapter of [Getting Started with the JDBC API](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/GettingStartedTOC.fm.html):

> (...) A `Driver` class is loaded, and
> therefore automatically registered
> with the `DriverManager`, in one of two
> ways:
>
> 1. by calling the method `Class.forName`. This explicitly loads
>    the driver class. Since it does not
>    depend on any external setup, this way
>    of loading a driver is the recommended
>    one for using the `DriverManager`
>    framework. The following code loads
>    the class `acme.db.Driver`:
>
>    ```
>     Class.forName("acme.db.Driver");
>    ```
>
> **If `acme.db.Driver` has been written so that loading it causes an
> instance to be created and also calls
> `DriverManager.registerDriver` with that
> instance as the parameter** (as it
> should do), then it is in the
> `DriverManager`'s list of drivers and
> available for creating a connection.
>
> 2. (...)
>
> In both of these cases, it is the responsibility of the newly-loaded `Driver` class to register itself by calling `DriverManager.registerDriver`. As mentioned, this should be done automatically when the class is loaded.

To register themselves during initialization, JDBC driver typically use a static initialization block like this:

```
package acme.db;

public class Driver {

    static {
        java.sql.DriverManager.registerDriver(new Driver());
    }
    
    ...
}
```

Calling `Class.forName("acme.db.Driver")` causes the initialization of the `acme.db.Driver` class and thus the execution of the static initialization block. And  `Class.forName("acme.db.Driver")` will indeed "create" an instance but this is just a consequence of how (good) JDBC Driver are implemented.

As a side note, I'd mention that all this is not required anymore with JDBC 4.0(added as a default package since Java 7) and the new auto-loading feature of JDBC 4.0 drivers. See [JDBC 4.0 enhancements in Java SE 6](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefjdbc4_0summary.html).

Comment: but still in this site :http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html

Comment: in the above site is written that:"Calling the Class.forName automatically creates an instance of a driver and registers it with the DriverManager, so you don't need to create an instance of the class. If you were to create your own instance, you would be creating an unnecessary duplicate, but it would do no harm." it means that by Class.forName you will create an instance outomatically and if you want to create the other it will make an unnecessary instance So both Calss.forName() and Class.forName().newInstance() will create an instance of the driver!!

Comment: JDBC drivers are "special", they are written with a static initialization block where an instance is created and passed as parameter of `DriverManager.registerDriver`. Calling `Class.forName` on a JDBC driver causes its initialization and thus the execution of the static block. Have a look at http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Database-DBMS/db-derby-10.2/org/apache/derby/jdbc/ClientDriver.java.htm for an example. So this is actually a particular case due to driver internals.

Comment: I've noticed that in [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7495850/543738), using Class.newInstance() is strongly discouraged.  It's recommended to use Class.getConstructor(), followed by Constructor.newInstance() in turn.  It avoids masking possible exceptions.

Comment: "newInstance allows to instantiate a class that you don't know until runtime" made my day. Thanks.

Comment: +1 for the detailed answer. One point though , With JDBC 4.0 one does not even need to use Class.forName .... Java's Service Provider Mechanism SPM loads the database driver automatically. One only needs to specify the driver jar in the classpath. Refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551648/understanding-javas-service-provider-mechanism-that-automatically-loads-the-jdb

Answer (score 37):

Class.forName() gives you the class object, which is useful for reflection. The methods that this object has are defined by Java, not by the programmer writing the class. They are the same for every class. Calling newInstance() on that gives you an instance of that class (i.e. calling `Class.forName("ExampleClass").newInstance()` it is equivalent to calling `new ExampleClass()`), on which you can call the methods that the class defines, access the visible fields etc.

Answer (score 33):

In JDBC world, the *normal* practice (according the JDBC API) is that you use `Class#forName()` to load a JDBC driver. The JDBC driver should namely register itself in [`DriverManager`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) inside a static block:

```
package com.dbvendor.jdbc;

import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class MyDriver implements Driver {

    static {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new MyDriver());
    }

    public MyDriver() {
        //
    }

}
```

Invoking `Class#forName()` will execute all [static initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893274/doubt-in-java-basics/1893321#1893321). This way the `DriverManager` can find the associated driver among the registered drivers by connection URL during [`getConnection()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection%28java.lang.String%29) which roughly look like follows:

```
public static Connection getConnection(String url) throws SQLException {
    for (Driver driver : registeredDrivers) {
        if (driver.acceptsURL(url)) {
            return driver.connect(url);
        }
    }
    throw new SQLException("No suitable driver");
}
```

But there were also *buggy* JDBC drivers, starting with the `org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver` as well known example, which incorrectly registers itself inside the **Constructor** instead of a static block:

```
package com.dbvendor.jdbc;

import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class BadDriver implements Driver {

    public BadDriver() {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(this);
    }

}
```

The only way to get it to work dynamically is to call `newInstance()` afterwards! Otherwise you will face at first sight unexplainable "SQLException: no suitable driver". Once again, this is a *bug* in the JDBC driver, not in your own code. Nowadays, no one JDBC driver should contain this bug. So you can (and should) leave the `newInstance()` away.

Answer (score 20):

1 : if you are interested only in the static block of the class , the loading the class only would do , and would execute static blocks then all you need is:

```
Class.forName("Somthing");
```

2 : if you are interested in loading the class , execute its static blocks and also want to access its its non static part , then you need an instance and then you need:

```
Class.forName("Somthing").newInstance();
```

Answer (score 7):

Class.forName() gets a reference to a Class, Class.forName().newInstance() tries to use the no-arg constructor for the Class to return a new instance.

Answer (score 4):

"Class.forName()" returns the Class-Type for the given name. "newInstance()" does return an instance of this class.

On the type you can't call directly any instance methods but can only use reflection for the class. If you want to work with an object of the class you have to create an instance of it (same as calling "new MyClass()").

Example for "Class.forName()"

```
Class myClass = Class.forName("test.MyClass");
System.out.println("Number of public methods: " + myClass.getMethods().length);
```

Example for "Class.forName().newInstance()"

```
MyClass myClass = (MyClass) Class.forName("test.MyClass").newInstance();
System.out.println("String representation of MyClass instance: " + myClass.toString());
```

Answer (score 3):

just adding to above answers, when we have a static code (ie code block is instance independent) that needs to be present in memory, we can have the class returned so we'll use Class.forname("someName") else if we dont have static code we can go for Class.forname().newInstance("someName") as it will load object level code blocks(non static) to memory

Answer (score 2):

No matter how many times you call Class.forName() method, Only once the static block gets executed not multiple time:

```java
package forNameMethodDemo;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class.forName("forNameMethodDemo.DemoClass");
        Class.forName("forNameMethodDemo.DemoClass");
        Class.forName("forNameMethodDemo.DemoClass");
        DemoClass demoClass = (DemoClass)Class.forName("forNameMethodDemo.DemoClass").newInstance();
    }
}


public class DemoClass {
    
    static {
        System.out.println("in Static block");
    }

    {
        System.out.println("in Instance block");
    }
}
```

output will be:

```
in Static block
in Instance block
```

This `in Static block` statement is printed only once not three times.

Answer (score 0):

`Class.forName()`-->forName() is the static method of Class class it returns Class class object used for reflection not user class object so you can only call Class class methods on it like `getMethods()`, `getConstructors()` etc.

If you care about only running static block of your(Runtime given) class and only getting information of methods,constructors,Modifier etc of your class you can do with this object which you get using `Class.forName()`

But if you want to access or call your class method (class which you have given at runtime) then you need to have its object so newInstance method of Class class do it for you.It create new instance of the class and return it to you .You just need to type-cast it to your class.

ex-:  suppose Employee is your class then

```java
Class a=Class.forName(args[0]); 

//args[0]=cmd line argument to give class at  runtime. 

Employee ob1=a.newInstance();
```

`a.newInstance()` is similar to creating object using `new Employee()`.

now you can access all your class visible fields and methods.