# Connecting Java Applet to MySQL DB - Communications link failure

Tags: java, php, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to connect my Java Applet to a MySQL Database. I know that it works, because I can connect to it on localhost and it retreives a list of records just fine. But when I put it on the internet, it doesn't work.

Here is my applet: http://mystikrpg.com/play

It's signed, but I keep getting the following exception:

> SQLException Get Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

How can this happen and what can I do to fix this problem?

Here's the applet source code: http://sodan.pastebin.com/jWKTgBSU

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To start, the following exception

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: 
  Communications link failure
```

can have the following causes:

1. IP address or hostname in JDBC URL is wrong.
2. Hostname in JDBC URL is not recognized by local DNS server.
3. Port number is missing or wrong in JDBC URL.
4. DB server is down.
5. DB server doesn't accept TCP/IP connections.
6. DB server has run out of connections.
7. Something in between Java and DB is blocking connections, e.g. a firewall or proxy.

---

Further, do you *realize* that an Java Applet physically runs at the **client** machine? I.e. the machine where the webbrowser runs. The client basically downloads the applet from the webserver and it get executed at client (local) machine. The JDBC connection string `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306` would try to connect to a MySQL database running at the very same machine as where the applet runs. You can't reasonably expect that every client on the world will run a MySQL DB, let alone with *your* database/table.

If all you want is to access the MySQL server hosted at the server machine (there where the webserver runs) and you want to let the applet communicate with it, then you really have to create and run a *webservice* at the webserver. Since you tagged this question with `[PHP]` as well, I guess that you're using PHP at the server side, in that case, just create a PHP script which executes the MySQL action accordingly based on the request parameters or pathinfo and returns the MySQL results as for example a [JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) or XML string. In the Applet, you can use the Java SE builtin [`java.net.URLConnection`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests) or the more convenienced [Apache HttpComponents Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/) to communicate with the webserver. E.g.

```
URLconnection connection = new URL(getCodeBase(), "script.php?action=getdetails&productid=1").openConnection();
InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();
// ...
```

In Java, you could process any JSON response using [Google Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688099/converting-json-to-java/1688182#1688182) any XML response using JAXP.

---

That said (and *unrelated* to the current problem), the JDBC driver name you're using is the **deprecated** `org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver`. I strongly recommend to use the correct driver name which was introduced over a decade ago to replace the old driver name: `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`. Further, the `Class#newInstance()` call after `Class#forName()` is also not needed. It was to workaround a *bug* in the old driver. Also see [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092659/what-is-difference-between-class-forname-and-class-forname-newinstance/2093236#2093236).

Comment: @Dan: did you spot that the part `java.net.URLConnection` in my answer is blue and clickable? Anyway, here's the link again, hope that helps more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests

Answer (score 0):

Applets did not have the sufficient privilege to access a file or DB, when it's remotely been accessed. That's the way JVM employs security via Sandboxing...

This is what I know about applet's privilege...

Comment: Maybe it's this line: con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jgame", props);

Comment: Of course, yes bro.. It tries to establish connection with the localhost, which will be denied by the JVM sandbox.

Comment: If it were a security issue, then you would rather have gotten an `AccessControlException` *before* the code can even attempt to connect the DB. In this particular case, the attempt to connect has already taken place, but the DB simply cannot be located.