# Connect to MySQL from Java

Tags: java, mysql, url, jdbc

I have a website, and I have a database in MySQL at that website as well. I can handle my database from phpMyAdmin online and it has name "dbPersons";

However I want to connect to that database from Java. I have downloaded JDBC, but I can't connect because of my connection string. I use the following connection string

```
String mySQLCredecials = "jdbc:mysql:thin:" + user + "/" + pass + "@jdbc:mysql:www.websiteName.net:2222/dbPersons";
```

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: And what are you doing with your string?

Comment: What error message do you see?

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql:thin:sampleUser/sampleUserPassword@jdbc:mysql:www.websiteName.net:2222/dbPersons
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
 at SQLcmds.DBConnector.connect(DBConnector.java:75)
 at SQLcmds.DBConnector.<init>(DBConnector.java:38)
 at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:11)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just look in the [MySQL JDBC driver documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) for the proper syntax.

> ### 21.3.5.1. Driver/Datasource Class Names, URL Syntax and Configuration Properties for Connector/J
>
> ...
>
> #### JDBC URL Format
>
> The JDBC URL format for MySQL Connector/J is as follows, with items in square brackets ([, ]) being optional:
>
> ```
> jdbc:mysql://[host][,failoverhost...][:port]/[database] »
> [?propertyName1][=propertyValue1][&propertyName2][=propertyValue2]...
> ```
>
> If the host name is not specified, it defaults to 127.0.0.1. If the port is not specified, it defaults to 3306, the default port number for MySQL servers.
>
> ```
> jdbc:mysql://[host:port],[host:port].../[database] »
> [?propertyName1][=propertyValue1][&propertyName2][=propertyValue2]...
> ```
>
> Here is a sample connection URL:
>
> ```
> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila?profileSQL=true
> ```

Yours is thus clearly wrong. The presence of `:thin` suggests that you were incorrectly reading the [Oracle JDBC driver documentation](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC#Thin_driver) instead of the MySQL one. Use the following JDBC URL:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://www.websiteName.net:2222/dbPersons";
```

And obtain the connection as follows:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
```

The `SQLException: No suitable driver` simply means that the given JDBC connection URL is not recognized by any of the so far loaded drivers. So apart from the wrong connection URL, another possible cause is that the JDBC driver supporting the URL isn't been loaded at all.

#### See also:

- [Connect Java to a MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/java-connectivity-with-mysql/2840358#2840358)
- [SQLException: No suitable driver found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982675/sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found/5983038#5983038)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a correct JDBC URL, yours is not correct.

Read here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

> **JDBC URL Format**
>
> The JDBC URL format for MySQL Connector/J is as follows, with items in
>   square brackets ([, ]) being optional:
>
> ```
> jdbc:mysql://[host][,failoverhost...][:port]/[database] »
> [?propertyName1][=propertyValue1][&propertyName2][=propertyValue2]...
> ```

...