# Failing to update a row in mySQL database using Java no error message

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc

I imported JDBC driver successfully into netbeans and tested the mySQL connection...works fine but after executing the query, the table is not updated in mySQL. I'm using a GUI to update these values and i'm getting absolutely no errors at all and i'm using exception handling as well!

//here's my code (updated)

```
  package DBConn;

  import java.sql.Connection;
  import java.sql.DriverManager;
  import java.sql.SQLException;
  import java.sql.Statement;
  import java.util.logging.Level;
  import java.util.logging.Logger;
  //import java.util.*;

  public class FrameDBTest extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public FrameDBTest() {
    initComponents();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jTextField4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Tapiwa's FlowNation CARS");
    setResizable(false);

    jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(153, 153, 255));

    jTextField1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Century Gothic", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    jTextField1.setName("JID"); // NOI18N
    jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jTextField2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Century Gothic", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    jTextField2.setName("JNAME"); // NOI18N
    jTextField2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jTextField3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Century Gothic", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    jTextField3.setName("JDISPLACE"); // NOI18N
    jTextField3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField3ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "FL 3", "FL 4", "FL 6", "V6", "V8", "V10", "V12", "V16", "W12", "W16" }));
    jComboBox1.setName("ComboCAR"); // NOI18N
    jComboBox1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jComboBox1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel1.setText("Name");

    jLabel2.setText("ID - INT");

    jLabel3.setText("Displacement - FLOAT");

    jLabel4.setText("Cylinders");

    jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Century Gothic", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
    jButton1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 102));
    jButton1.setText("SAVE");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jTextField4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Century Gothic", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    jTextField4.setName("JNAME"); // NOI18N
    jTextField4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField4ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel6.setText("Name");

    jButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Century Gothic", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
    jButton2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 102));
    jButton2.setText("SAVE");
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(22, 22, 22)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 123, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4))
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(jTextField3)
                        .addComponent(jTextField2)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1)
                        .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 361, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel6)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 235, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(24, 24, 24))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 123, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(34, 34, 34))))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(35, 35, 35)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 36, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 36, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel6)))
            .addGap(28, 28, 28)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 36, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 28, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel4))
            .addGap(25, 25, 25)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 36, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel3))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 42, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 42, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 16)); // NOI18N
    jLabel5.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 153, 153));
    jLabel5.setText("FlowNation CARS");

    jPanel2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(153, 153, 153));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 947, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 42, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    jPanel3.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 102));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
    jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
    jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 22, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(23, 23, 23)
            .addComponent(jLabel5)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel5)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jTextField3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                           

@SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    try
    {


        Connection CC = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/CS","root","carrizo");
        Statement ST = (Statement) CC.createStatement();

        //String newdata;
        ST.execute("INSERT INTO carz VALUES('"+jTextField2.getText()+"',"+jTextField1.getText()+",'"+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()+"',"+jTextField3.getText()+")");
        //ST.executeUpdate(newdata);
    }

    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getSQLState());
        e.getMessage();
        e.getErrorCode();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    finally
    {
        System.out.println("\n\nExecuted...\n"); 
    };

}                                        












 ![mySQL database and table][1]
```

Comment: Replace your `catch` block with this `catch(SQLException e)
    {
           e.printStackTrace();
    }`

Comment: Please limit your code to the relevant (non-UI) code.

Comment: Sorry for that...i'll do just that next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notes about your code:

Note you're using [Statement.execute(String sql)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute%28java.lang.String%29) method which is mainly intended to perform database queries. To execute INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements it's recommended the use of [Statement.executeUpdate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29) method instead.

Also note your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should take a look to [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) interface which is a subinterface of [Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) and will help you to avoid this. Take a look to [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) trail.

For instance you can refactor your code as follows:

```
Integer param1 = Integer.valueOf(jTextField2.getText());
Integer param2 = Integer.valueOf(jTextField1.getText());
Object param3 = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
Integer param4 = Integer.valueOf(jTextField3.getText());

String sql = "INSERT INTO carz VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement statement = CC.prepareStatement(sql);
statement.setInt(1, param1);
statement.setInt(2, param1);    
statement.setObject(3, param3);
statement.setInt(4, param4);

int result = statement.executeUpdate();
```

You might want to take a look to this excelent tutorial as well:

- [MySQL and Java JDBC - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html)

---

Note code within `actionPerformed()` method is executed in the [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) (aka EDT) which is a single thread where Swing components creation/update and event handling take place. Time consuming tasks (like database calls) may block this thread causing your GUI become unresponsive. To avoid this you should use [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) class to perform heavy tasks in a background thread and update Swing components in the EDT.

---

Empty `catch` blocks ignoring exceptions are not a good practice at all. You should at least print the stack trace:

```
catch(SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); // log the exception is even better 
}
```

---

About this comment:

> but for those textfields without single quotes...they are actually
>   ints

Maybe [JSpinner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) or [JFormattedTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) are a better choice in this case.

---

Finally but not less important, always follow [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf). Variable names start with lower-case and must be meaningful.

Comment: Wow...thanx...learnt a lot...i'll do just that and i'll get back to you!

Comment: @tpmabb you're welcome :) Don't hesitate to ask any doubt you may have about this answer.

Comment: @ dic19 Ever since I added e.printStackTrace i've been getting a driver error but my other test program is working fine...what could be possibly wrong here? I'll make time for the tutorial

Comment: @tpmabb did you see this post? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5983038/1795530 Make sure the URL you're trying to connect with is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not handling exceptions, just an empty catch statement.

Comment: Thanx..but i'm a rookie ...any suggested code i can put in the catch block

Comment: Print the exception stacktrace, so you can read the error thrown in the try block.
Something like: System.out.println(e);  or ...println(e.getMessage())
My guess is that, during the db operation an exception is raised, you catch it (through catch block) but you don't do anything with it.

Comment: You should also put the database port on your connection string.
Have a look at [Mysql Java connectivity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/java-connectivity-with-mysql/2840358#2840358)

Comment: Added port...not helping.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO carz VALUES('"+jTextField2.getText()+"',"+jTextField1.getText()+",'"+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()+"',"+jTextField3.getText()+")");
```

In the above insert query you are not enclosing varchars with `'`

change it to like this

```
INSERT INTO carz VALUES('"+jTextField2.getText()+"','"+jTextField1.getText()+"','"+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()+"','"+jTextField3.getText()+"')");
```

Comment: Thanx @JqueryLearner...but for those textfields without single quotes...they are actually ints

Comment: @tpmabb If they are `int` then you must convert them into `int` using `Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText())`.

Comment: I understand...tried but still not working...i'm not getting any conversion error or any other error. It's just that the table is not being updated!

Comment: @tpmabb I am sure you are having errors. If you do `e.printStackTrace()` in `catch` block then you will get all errors.

Comment: You're right...I am getting a no suitable driver error but I used the exact same driver (as posted above) in another working program

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you are entering numeric values for the ID and displacement, you should be ok without enclosing with varchars. But really, what you should do is just put a `System.out.println(e.getSQLState())` or `e.getMessage()` or `e.getErrorCode()` in the catch statement and just see what the error is. That will go a long way in figuring out this issue.

Try modifying the getConnection part to:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); // Setup the connection with the DB 
connect = DriverManager .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/feedback?" + "user=sqluser&password=sqluserpw");
```

And as AJ commented, put `e.printStackTrace()` in your catch block as well to get the most detailed info on what's going on in the JDBC process.

Comment: Cool...let me try that now.

Comment: Tried that...it's returning 08001

Comment: I think that is a "No suitable driver" error. Are you sure you included the mysql jar file for jdbc? I know you said you already tested the connection and it seemed to work. But googling sqlstate 08001 seems to point to that

Comment: I'm not sure if the Class.forName line is required either.  Try the following two lines of code for setting up the connection. Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      // Setup the connection with the DB
      connect = DriverManager
          .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/feedback?"
              + "user=sqluser&password=sqluserpw");

Comment: You know, the weird thing is that i have another program that works fine on the same machine it's just this one (with the same code except it's a different database) which isn't working. So I don't think it's a problem with the jdbc driver.

Comment: Added the e.printStackTrace(); line and I got this:                                             java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/CS at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596)                                                                             But my other program works fine with the driver...I'm using Netbeans 7.4 and mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar