# Java MySQL Login

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I get this error when I try to login : 
This is my 1'st attempt to connect to a mySQL DB with Java.
Really need some help, thanks in advance.

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql:localhost
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at z_applets.NewJFrame.jButton1ActionPerformed(NewJFrame.java:114)
    at z_applets.NewJFrame.access$100(NewJFrame.java:16)
    at z_applets.NewJFrame$2.actionPerformed(NewJFrame.java:55)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

This is my code :

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */


package z_applets;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author ExtremeSwat
 */
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame
     */
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPasswordField1 = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("Username");

        jLabel2.setText("Password");

        jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(38, 38, 38)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addGap(20, 20, 20)))
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jPasswordField1)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 110, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(274, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(53, 53, 53))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(59, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(25, 25, 25)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jPasswordField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                .addGap(147, 147, 147))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        String username = jTextField1.getText();
        String password = jPasswordField1.getText();

        //System.out.println(username + " " + password);

       // if(username == "ed" && password == "123")

//        if(username.equals("ed") && password.equals("123"))
//            System.out.println("check");

        try
        {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:localhost", "root", "password");
            Statement st = con.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * from username WHERE username = '" + username + "' AND password='" + password + "'");
            int count = 0;

            while(rs.next())
            {
                count++;
            }

            if(username.equals("") && password.equals(""))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter login name or password", "error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

            }
            else if(count>0)
            {
                System.out.println("Great success!");

            }

            else
            {
                System.out.println("Not great success");

            }
        }catch(Exception e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }                                        

    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField jPasswordField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

This is my table and it's contents  : 
http://prntscr.com/3cr2f8

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQLException: No suitable driver found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982675/sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found)

Comment: try tis tutorial, it should help you http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html

Comment: Thank you guys, especially the tutorial. It works pretty much awesomely, I shall return at a later time with additional comments/inquiries

Comment: If your question was answered you should ask new questions as a new topic.  Please don't extend an answered question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a JDBC driver for MySQL in your classpath.  Then you need to run Class.forName("driver-class-name") to load the appropriate driver.

The driver should be supplied by MySQL.  Look in the bin or lib folder of the install directory for MySQL.

--EDIT--

The classname of the driver is usually something like com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.  You can find this in the MySQL docs.

-- EDIT 2 --

MySql Docs for the latest version : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-installing-classpath.html

According to this:

```
To use the driver with the JDBC DriverManager,
use com.mysql.jdbc.Driver as the class that implements java.sql.Driver.
```

Looks like I guessed right on the Driver name.

Answer (score 1):

The connection string `jdbc:mysql:localhost` is wrong.  It should be of the form `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cards`.

(From your screenshot, it looks like `cards` is the correct database name.  Feel free to change that part of the connection string if `cards` is wrong.)

If you still get this error after changing your connection string, then the MySQL driver JAR (usually named something like `mysql-connector-java-5.N.NN.jar`) is not on the classpath.