# Error in GCP BigQuery Data Transfer Service: No suitable driver found for jdbc:redshift://

Tags: jdbc, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, amazon-redshift, google-cloud-data-transfer

we followed Google Cloud Platform link https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/redshift-migration#console to setup Data Transfer from AWS RedShift to BigQuery dataset. But we are getting following error:

18:51:01    Unable to proceed: Could not connect with provided parameters: No suitable driver found for jdbc:redshift://redshift-xyz-bq.c7nxtqwerty23.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/dev
18:50:30    Transfer load date: 20210120
18:50:29    Dispatched run to data source with id xxxxxxx

We verified all the required parameters and sure that values are correctly set. Can you please help with this issue?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The error indicates that you don't have the right driver installed (or at least, not loaded).

Comment: Thanks Mark, as we are performing this task from GCP console so we don't have any control on drivers being used within GCP back end implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone for your prompt suggestions. Actually the error message was misguiding us. The issue was with AWS subnet that was somehow not allowing us in (could be private subnet in the RedShift Subnet Group; could not see real details before deleting the POC environment). Once we created RedShift cluster using Subnet Group having only public subnets then it worked very well. Hope this helps someone at some point of time.

Comment: Zamir, I'm getting the same error, Although I have setup a VPN connection and provided the private IP range as required. Do you have more details?

Answer (score -1):

Please bear in mind that, according to [1], *"A JDBC URL specified with the former format of jdbc:postgresql://endpoint:port/database still works"*.

Consequently, I suggest that you change the start of the URL of your driver from `jdbc:redshift` to `jdbc:postgresql`.

If the prior change does not work, please review the following related questions [2] to [6], since it seems like this exception is frequently thrown when the driver URL does not match (pay extra attention at the use of single and double quotes) or when the driver has not been registered before trying to establish the connection.

I hope this helped solve the issue you are experiencing :)

[1]:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection.html#obtain-jdbc-url

[2]:

[SQLException: No suitable driver found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982675/sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found)

[3]:

[No suitable driver found for 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146793/no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql-localhost3306-mysql)

[4]:

[The infamous java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911253/the-infamous-java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found)

[5]:

[How to fix: "No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname" error when using pools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556664/how-to-fix-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql-localhost-dbname-error-w)

[6]:

[java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22384710/java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql-localhost3306)

Comment: Thanks rodvictor, as these activities are being performed from GCP Console (UI) so driver specific configuration can't be modified by end users. I checked all your links but they are related to using JDBC from some custom application where we have control on configuration.

Comment: It is usually better to make links a natural part of the body of text instead of listing them like you do now. And if you list them, consider using an actual numbered list.

Comment: We even tried using jdbc:postgresql instead of jdbc:redshift in URL but same result.