# What is difference between these two statement?

Tags: android, mysql, jdbc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is difference between “Class.forName()” and “Class.forName().newInstance()”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092659/what-is-difference-between-class-forname-and-class-forname-newinstance)

In my android apps to connect mysql server using jdbc connection. In that I want to know difference

```
`Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`
```

and

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

and also how to set the timeout functions, when server is not connected?

Comment: Please check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092659/what-is-difference-between-class-forname-and-class-forname-newinstance

Comment: check this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092659/what-is-difference-between-class-forname-and-class-forname-newinstance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Class.forName()` returns a Class object -- an object that represents a particular Java class.

`newInstance()` -- a method of java.lang.Class -- will use the no-argument constructor of the represented class to create an instance of that class.

**For your question:** (Reference from http://www.coderanch.com/t/385654/java/java/Difference-between-Class-forName-Class)

`Class.forName()` gets a reference to a Class, `Class.forName().newInstance()` tries to use the no-arg constructor for the Class to return a new instance. No surprises so far. Another common use for `Class.forName()` is to cause the Class to be loaded, since some types of Classes have side-effects from the loading process which is required for other purposes. `JDBC` is a large user of this process, since the Driver class is required to register itself with the `DriverManager` Class when it gets loaded.

In the deep dark days of Java, probably v1.1.8 but possibly up to Java 1.2, there was an issue that the default `ClassLoader` would not load a Class until it had an instance created. In these cases, JDBC code would fail if you used `Class.forName()` rather than `Class.forName().newInstance()`.

While `newInstance()` would create an instance that got immediately thrown away, it was required to make `Class.forName()` work correctly. This work around is no longer required.