# Dynamic class declare and instantiate?

Tags: java, class, dynamic

Is it possible in java to declare and instantiate a class at runtime?

I am attempting following code:

```
    public static void t4() {
    Object o = new Object() {
        private String uid = "1";
        private String name = "2";

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public String getUid() {
            return uid;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public void setUid(String uid) {
            this.uid = uid;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return uid + " " + name;
        }
    };
```

But, I would want this to happen using reflection, cause i will be injecting attributes into pojo from xml source.

Any more thoughts?

Comment: Dive deep into [`Reflection API`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html)

Comment: and [`ClassLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html)

Comment: A bit of googling should turn up hundreds of pages on this...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is difference between "Class.forName()" and "Class.forName().newInstance()"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092659/what-is-difference-between-class-forname-and-class-forname-newinstance)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible upto some degree to dynamically compile a class using the JDK6.0's Java Compiler API from a String object(holding the code).

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JDK-6/CompilingfromMemory.htm refer here.

The code also shows you how to dynamically instantiate that "newly compiled" class from a class file(using Class.forName()) method.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are answers all over the internet for this... 
here you go with one

[What is the difference between "Class.forName()" and "Class.forName().newInstance()"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092659/what-is-difference-between-class-forname-and-class-forname-newinstance)

The answer of above post demonstrates how to create a new instance on run time.