# Java database connection. Trying to log in to jframe via sql get logic error

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc

I have a swing `jframe` that has a login screen and I'm trying to execute a `phpmyadmin` database query. It connects to the database but it doesn't allow me to log in and just infinity says "invalid username or password" Here is the code.

```
JPasswordField jpfpass;
JLabel jlabuser, jlabpass;

public RychlikSystemversion0(String name) {
    super(name);
    btnlogin = new JButton("Login");
    btenreset = new JButton("Reset");
    btnexit = new JButton("Exit");

    jtfuser = new JTextField();
    jpfpass = new JPasswordField();

    jlabuser = new JLabel("Ussername");
    jlabpass = new JLabel("Password");

    this.setLayout(null);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    btnlogin.addActionListener(this);
    btenreset.addActionListener(this);
    btnexit.addActionListener(this);

    jlabuser.setBounds(10, 10, 120, 20);
    jlabpass.setBounds(10, 30, 120, 20);
    jtfuser.setBounds(140, 10, 300, 20);
    jpfpass.setBounds(140, 30, 300, 20);

    btnlogin.setBounds(140, 55, 100, 20);
    btenreset.setBounds(240, 55, 100, 20);
    btnexit.setBounds(340, 55, 100, 20);

    this.add(jlabuser);
    this.add(jlabpass);
    this.add(jtfuser);
    this.add(jpfpass);
    this.add(btnlogin);
    this.add(btenreset);
    this.add(btnexit);

    this.setSize(500, 300);
    this.setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    //String USERNAME = "root";
    //String PASSWORD = "root ";
    //String CONN_STRING = "jdbc:mysql://localhost::3307/osdesign";

    Connection connection;
    PreparedStatement ps;
    try {
        String dbName = "osdesign";
        String dbUserName = "root";
        String dbPassword = "";
        //String u = jtfuser.getText();
        //String p =jpfpass.getName();
        String connectionString = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/" + dbName + "?user="
                + dbUserName + "&password=" + dbPassword
                + "&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8";
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connected!");
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM `userlist` WHERE `UsrName` = ? AND `UsrPass` = ?";
        ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

        jtfuser.setText("Test");
        jpfpass.setText("Test");
        ps.setString(1, jtfuser.getText());
        ps.setString(2, jpfpass.getName());
        //JFrame panel = new JFrame();
        ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();
        btnlogin.equals(result);
        // panel.add(btnlogin);
        //   panel.add(jpfpass.getName(),btnlogin);
        if (result.next()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Sucessful");  //Wont execute statement
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "Invalid user name or password");     //Always does this
    }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RychlikSystemversion0.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    RychlikSystemversion0 ls = new RychlikSystemversion0("System login");
}
```

I've tried several things it still doesn't allow me to login. Any help?

Comment: what username and password you try with and exist in database?

Comment: You should check your username and password with MySQL, use CMD to connect to mySQL, command -> mysql -u root -p admin

Comment: Did you search the forum first before posting the question? Like maybe this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852195/drivermanager-no-suitable-driver-mysql. I would always use the `getConnection(...()` method where you pass the user/password as separate parameters to keep the connection string simpler so you are less likely to make a syntax mistake.

Comment: @camickr i think the OP use a static username and password `jtfuser.setText("Test"); jpfpass.setText("Test");`

Comment: @YCF_L, that wasn't my point. Look at the OP's "connectionString" and all the string concatenation which could cause a syntax error if not done correctly. instead use: `getConnection(connectionString, user, password)`. With less formatting in the connection string you are less likely to have syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with:

```
jpfpass = new JPasswordField();
//[..]
ps.setString(2, jpfpass.getName());
```

The method [`getName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getName--), does not provide you with the password in the field, instead it gives you *the name of the component* (which in your code isn't even set).

If you want to obtain the password from the `JPasswordField`, you need to use [`getPassword()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#getPassword--). This method returns a `char[]`, so you need to change your code to use:

```
ps.setString(2, new String(jpfpass.getPassword()));
```

If in the future you are confronted with problems like this, first check your assumptions. Step through your code in a debugger and check if the values are what you expect, or just add some debug `System.out.println(..)` of the relevant values.