# Database ConnectionError

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp, servlets, mysql-connector

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at servlet.Signup.doGet(Signup.java:34)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: Make sure the driver jar is in WEB-INF/lib

Comment: `Class.forName()` didn't find a class named `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`. You should provide a database driver. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15852220/573032) answer you can learn how to load a database driver.

Comment: @RomanC. In fact, for current drivers, that answer is no longer really applicable. If you still *had* to load the class, in fact the OP's class name would probably be right for current versions of the MySql driver. But you don't. And you really shouldn't, as your code will break if and when the driver class name changes

Comment: @g00se That answer is made a decade ago, and ofcause the driver has changed as the class name, technology, and you didn't born or all of the above. Nevertheless in the linked duplicate the driver has an old name.

Comment: @RomanC, the point I'm making is that you *shouldn't* load the driver at all

Comment: @g00se I don't understand who are you telling this and why? I'm not intended to answer this question and left only my comment. Because my answer helped a lot of people and *might* help more because it is related to this problem.