# How do i create an instance of a class based on a String without making multiple switches and if's?

Tags: java, string, class, instance, creation

hi I'm making a program that receives a String as input and based on that String i create an instance of a class.

The problem is that my program may have new classes in the future and i would like that when that happens i dont have to make much changes to my code, so i would like to avoid using chains of if's or switches.

for example if i receive "Class1" as input i want to create an instance of that class

but if in the future i want to be able to create an instance of "Class2" i dont want to have to change the previous code by adding a new if or a new case on a switch.

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the use of Reflection API.

your string would have the full path of the package also

```
String yourClassPathPackage = "com.your.class.path.YourClass";
YourClass = (YourClass) Class.forName(yourClassPathPackage).newInstance();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Class.forName(classNameReceivedAsParameter).newInstance();
```

You will need to concatenate the package name to the parameter to obtain the full class name. And, obviously, this will only work for classes which have a no-arg constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the forName function of class. The solution is described here : [What is the difference between "Class.forName()" and "Class.forName().newInstance()"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092659/what-is-difference-between-class-forname-and-class-forname-newinstance)

Answer (score 0):

As said you can use reflection API:

```
String yourClassPathPackage = "com.your.class.path.YourClass" 
YourClass = (YourClass) Class.forName(yourClassPathPackage).newInstance();
```

But if you have arguments in the constructor you can use the get Constructor method to get the constructor with the right arguments:

```
Class.forName(yourClassPathPackage).getConstructor(String.class).newInstance("MyClass");
```