# Why does calling Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") register the MySQL for JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

As explained in [What is the difference between "Class.forName()" and "Class.forName().newInstance()"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092659/what-is-the-difference-between-class-forname-and-class-forname-newinstanc), the method Class.forName() does the following:

*Calling Class.forName(String) returns the Class object associated with the class or interface with the given string name*

But, if it only does that, why is it then neccesary to call this method in order to use MySQL with Java? Without it I get the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/calender
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at Database.main(Database.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

Comment: You must be using an old driver, because all newer JDBC drivers will auto-register without having to call `Class.forName`.

Comment: Where can I download a new MySQL driver? The latest I can see is 5.0.8 on MySQL website: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/3.1.html

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/. Currently 5.1.36.

Comment: 5.0.8 is from 2007-10-09. A bit outdated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It registers it because it loads the class into memory and runs the class's static initializers. The static initializer code then calls into the JDBC framework to say "Hi there, I'm a JDBC driver" (by calling [`DriverManager.registerDriver`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#registerDriver-java.sql.Driver-)).

E.g., the driver class will look *vaguely* like this:

```
package com.example.jdbc;

import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class Driver implements java.sql.Driver {
    static {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new Driver());
    }

    // ...implementation...
}
```

Then when you do `Class.forName("com.example.jdbc.Driver")`, it loads the class and runs the static initializer, which creates an instance and registers it with the `DriverManager`.

---

I should note that [as Andreas says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32922459/why-does-calling-class-fornamecom-mysql-jdbc-driver-register-the-mysql-for-j/32922475#comment53671714_32922459), modern JDBC drivers don't need you to do this.

Comment: Excellent explanation :)