# Way to initialize HttpServlet in web.xml

Tags: servlets, web-applications, controller, initialization, web.xml

I wrote a controller class for my webapp, which inherits from HttpServlet.

```
public abstract class BaseController extends HttpServlet {
protected ClientsProvider clientsProvider;

@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {
    clientsProvider = (ClientsProvider) getServletContext().getAttribute(
        "clientsProvider");
    if (clientsProvider == null) {
        clientsProvider = new ClientsProvider();
        getServletContext().setAttribute("clientsProvider", clientsProvider);
    }
    super.init();
}
```

CommonsProvider is another class in which I initialized all the clients I used in this project.

Now I want to use web.xml to do the init() work, instead of writing such init() code here. Like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>BaseController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>myproject.controller.BaseController</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>clientsProvider</param-name>
        <param-value>clientsProvider</param-value>
    </context-param>
</servlet>
```

The above code does not work because the param values are not set property. What I need in the param-value is a new ClientsProvider() object. In this case, is it still possible to do the init() work in web.xml? Thanks!

Comment: You cannot do that declarative in web.xml but you can have a lifecycle listener or filter for such cross cutting concerns. DI frameworks use the same mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web.xml cannot do this, because there will be no instance of the ClientProvider at startup time. You can use a [DI](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Injection) container like the [Spring Framework](https://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/) to do that. If you dont want to use any framework, you could pass the full qualified class name as a String and use [Class.forName(...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092659/what-is-the-difference-between-class-forname-and-class-forname-newinstanc) in your servlet.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>clientsProvider</param-name>
    <param-value>your.package.ClientsProvider</param-value>
    <!--<param-value>your.package.AnotherClientsProvider</param-value>-->
</context-param>
```