# Java enum valueOf() with multiple values?

Tags: java, enums

I have a problem in Java using Enums.
I have read the documentation about assigning value parameters to Enums.
But, my question is what about multiple values, is it possible?

This what I would like to achieve:
I have an Enum for languages. Each language is represented by its name and some shorter aliases (not always, and not always the same number of aliases)

Here is an example:

```
public enum Language{
English("english", "eng", "en", "en_GB", "en_US"),
German("german", "de", "ge"),
Croatian("croatian", "hr", "cro"),
Russian("russian")
}
```

Can I just define an Enum like this and get the right enum values by calling Language.valueOf() ???

Comment: I'd recommend you to see my articles: http://java.dzone.com/articles/enum-tricks-customized-valueof
and
http://java.dzone.com/articles/enum-tricks-hierarchical-data Although I am not sure I understand exactly what do you really want I believe that at least one of these articles contain answer to your question.

Comment: @AlexR: thanks! A decade has passed and such problems still exist :) I suppose hierarchical data per your article is a suitable answer here, as long as the code which cares about the values would be content with custom `is()` lookups (e.g. `if (lang.is("English"))`) with all aliases being "sub-items" in hierarchy. Might even report the display-name (override `toString()`) by looking up until grandparent class is `null`. I think some benefits of native `enum` are lost however, e.g. `switch/case` support becomes messy. Feels unfortunate that they did not make an "enum with aliases" part of Java.

Answer (score 72):

This is probably similar to what you're trying to achieve.

```
public enum Language{
    English("english", "eng", "en", "en_GB", "en_US"),
    German("german", "de", "ge"),
    Croatian("croatian", "hr", "cro"),
    Russian("russian");

    private final List<String> values;

    Language(String ...values) {
        this.values = Arrays.asList(values);
    }

    public List<String> getValues() {
        return values;
    }
}
```

Remember enums are a class like the others; `English("english", "eng", "en", "en_GB", "en_US")` is calling the enum constructor.

You could then retrieve the enum value corresponding to a string through a search method (you can put it as a static method in the enum again).

```
public static Language find(String name) {
    for (Language lang : Language.values()) {
        if (lang.getValues().contains(name)) {
            return lang;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I could be misreading this, but I think he wants to be able to do Language.valueOf("eng") or Language.valueOf("english"), and get the same enum instance back.

Comment: Ok that is not possible with the defaul valueOf method; I edited the answer to include a method to obtain that effect.

Comment: Yeah, I was sorta confused too, really it's a clever idea I think, but not possible.

Comment: +1.  Couple of things you may consider are changing your example so that it first tries to delegate to `valueOf` (so the typical case "English" is covered), and maybe using a `static Map<String, Language>` instead of an instance member `List` to make lookups easier.

Comment: @Mark - `valueOf()` attempts to match the actual constant name (in this case, `ENGLISH`) rather than any value associated with the constant ("English"). Plus, it throws an exception if it doesn't match.

Comment: @Anon: In this case, the constant name is actually `English`, not `ENGLISH` (don't forget to actually look at the code and/or question before refuting someone).  The `find(String)` method doesn't check for "English" since it's not included in the constructor parameters.  Hence my comment and suggestion.  The point about the exception is a good one, but not a deal breaker since exceptions can be caught if need be.  An alternative would be to explicitly add the enum to the list (`values.add(getName())`).

Comment: The other alternative is to move the `valueOf()` call delegation to the end instead of the beginning.  I think my original point is irrelevant anyway though, since it looks like the OP is fine with only returning a result for the strings listed in the arguments of the constructor.  After that it's just a matter of case sensitivity.

Comment: @Flavio, if the enum values are associated with only a single value, like `ENGLISH("Eng")`, will it be possible to get `Languages.ENGLISH` through `Language.valueOf("Eng")`?

Comment: No, the `valueOf` method only works with the Java name of the enum (i.e. `ENGLISH` in your example). You must use the `find` method also for those cases. Unless *all* have a single value, but then this is the wrong post :)

Answer (score 18):

Mapping a string to a enum value, is typically what the `valueOf` static method is doing for you. So if you want to accomplish this with the use of synonyms, you will have to develop something similar. Because we cannot override a static method, and I do not think we want to in this case, we will name it differently: `fromString` should be appropriate.

```
public enum Language { 
  ENGLISH("eng", "en", "en_GB", "en_US"),   
  GERMAN("de", "ge"),   
  CROATIAN("hr", "cro"),   
  RUSSIAN("ru"),
  BELGIAN("be",";-)");

  static final private Map<String,Language> ALIAS_MAP = new HashMap<String,Language>(); 
  static { 
    for (Language language:Language.values()) { 
      // ignoring the case by normalizing to uppercase
      ALIAS_MAP.put(language.name().toUpperCase(),language); 
      for (String alias:language.aliases)
        ALIAS_MAP.put(alias.toUpperCase(),language);
    } 
  } 

  static public boolean has(String value) { 
    // ignoring the case by normalizing to uppercase
    return ALIAS_MAP.containsKey(value.toUpperCase());
  } 

  static public Language fromString(String value) { 
    if (value == null) throw new NullPointerException("alias null"); 
    Language language = ALIAS_MAP.get(value.toUpperCase()); 
    if (language == null)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not an alias: "+value); 
    return language; 
  } 

  private List<String> aliases; 
  private Language(String... aliases) { 
    this.aliases = Arrays.asList(aliases); 
  } 
}
```

As a benefit of this type of implementation we can, as demonstrated, also easily implement the `has` static method to test if a given alias is part of the enum value set. At the same time, we applied some good naming conventions:

- the enum values go in uppercase, to indicate that they are in actuality static finals (singleton instances).
- at the same time, we also put all the other static finals all caps.

Note that we do not have to repeat the name of the enum value itself: we always consider it's own name automatically (gets added to the ALIAS_MAP), and on top we normalize everything to uppercase to make it case insensitive.

Seems big, but while using the enum, it looks pretty:

```
public void main() {
  Language myLanguage = Language.fromString("en_GB");
  if (myLanguage == Language.ENGLISH) {
    System.out.println("Yes, I know, you understand English!");
  }
}
```

The backing container for the aliases is a `Map`, a `HashMap` to be more specific. The `HashMap` provides a fast access path to the aliases, and is also easy to grow. Whenever we think about 'indexing' something, likely a `HashMap` should be our first choice.

Note that for transparent use, we store both the name of the enum constant itself (retrieved through the `name()` method), and all the aliases. We could have implemented this differently by first attempting to do the lookup using the built-in `valueOf` static method. It is a design choice, but we would potentially have to deal with additional exceptions etc.

Answer (score 3):

In short, no.

The parameter for the valueOf() method must be only the String of the enum constant type.  So it cannot vary, or lookup possible values.  See the [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29).

You need to write your own utility method to return the proper enum type for the given values.

Answer (score 2):

Normalize the data:

```
public enum LanguageCode
{
  ENGLISH,
  GERMAN,
  CROATIAN,
  RUSSIAN,
  // ...
}
// (add whatever initialization you want to that
```

Then

```
public enum Language{
  english(ENGLISH),
  eng(ENGLISH),
  en(ENGLISH),
  en_GB(ENGLISH),
  // ...
}
```

etc.

Comment: Hmmm...I don't think that will work.
LanguageEnum members would then be english, eng, en, en_GB...
and not ENGLISH,GERMAN...

Answer (score 1):

Wow, really quick reply :)
Thanks guys.

Andy is right. I want to call Language.valueOf("eng") or Language.valueOf("english") and get Language.English as return.

I already have a utility function that does this, but it's not very nice.
Switch function that checks string values and return appropriate enum instance.

But there is a lot of code rewriting (I have cca 30-40 languages).
And if I want to add a language, I have to add it to enum, and implement a new check in the utility class.

I'll try Flavios approach.
Just one question.
Your constructor, shouldn't it be?

```
Language(List<String> values) {
    this.values = Arrays.asList(values);
}
```

Comment: If you use your kind of constructor (you must remove the `Arrays.asList` call to make it compile), the instances would have to be created with `English(Arrays.asList("english", "eng", "en", "en_GB", "en_US"))`. You can also store the values as a simple array instead of a List... the search would be slightly more awkward though.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively add a method, so your enums and constructor can be more clean if the structure is more complicated:

```
public Language getLanguage(String code){
  switch(code){
    case "en":
    case "en_GB":
    ...
    case "eng":
      return ENGLISH;
    case "rus":
    case "russian":
      return RUSSIAN;
  }
}
```