# What structure should I use to store key and list of possible values?

Tags: java, collections

I want to store information about filetype and possible files extension.
What I want to do is if I provide file extension and this extension is on the list I will return key for it.

Eg:

```
Map<Filetype, List<String>> extensionMapping= new HashMap<>();
extensionMapping.put(Filetype.IMAGE, Arrays.asList("jpg", "jpeg"));
extensionMapping.put(Filetype.WORD, Arrays.asList("doc", "docx"));
extensionMapping.put(Filetype.EXCEL, Arrays.asList("xls", "xlsx", "xlsm"));
extensionMapping.put(Filetype.PPT, Arrays.asList("ppt", "pptx", "pptm"));`
```

And then I want to do something like this:

```
return extensionMapping.get().contains("jpg");
```

which for string "jpg" returns me `Filetype.IMAGE`.

Which collection should I use?

Comment: It seems like your extensions are unique per key, so I'd opt for a `Map<String, FileType>` where the key is the extension.

Comment: Why not `Map <String, Filetype>` is that's you most common query?

Comment: I feel current one is also good `Map<Filetype, List<String>>

Comment: [`EnumMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) is a better container for cases where the key is of a single `Enum` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean you can do that now also by having same structure `Map<Filetype, List<String>>`. In `Map` any of values (which is List of strings contains `"jpg"`) will return `Filetype.IMAGE` or else it will return `Filetype.None`

```
extensionMapping.entrySet().stream().filter(entry->entry.getValue().contains("jpg")).map(Map.Entry::getKey)
      .findFirst().orElse(Filetype.None);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would create a reverse map, with the keys being the extension and the values the file type:

```
Map<String, Filetype> byExtension = new HashMap<>();
extensionMapping.forEach((type, extensions) -> 
        extensions.forEach(ext -> byExtension.put(ext, type)));
```

Now, for a given extension, you simply do:

```
FileType result = byExtension.get("jpg"); // FileType.IMAGE
```

Comment: This is probably the better answer. Here is another posting to a similar question, where the mapping is being made part of the enum through a `static Map`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12659023/744133