# Spring Boot translate camelCase String to Enum

Tags: java, string, spring-boot, enums, mapping

How can I obtain the enum corresponding value from a given `String` in camel case format? For instance, for the following enum:

```
public enum Status {
  NEVER_DONE, DONE
}
```

and this controller:

```
public interface QuestionsController {
  @GetMapping(value = "/questions", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  List<Question> getQuestions(@RequestParam String status);
}
```

How could I map the received `String` to the corresponding value from `Status` so these requirements are met:

- `NEVER_DONE` and `neverDone` map to `NEVER_DONE`.
- `DONE` and `done` map to `DONE`.

Comment: Most probably you are looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4198066/3981539)

Comment: but I have to call explicitly `find` within `getQuestions`. Is there a way to make Spring automatically make this mapping before doing anything else in the controller?

Comment: I do not think that would be possible with Spring at the moment. From design perspective it is always good to do thorough validation of incoming request body so that injection based attacks won't happen. And the validation logic is best written by the application developer himself than the framework developer.