# how to define constants or enum in java when a value has a value to store

Tags: java, enums, constants

I am struggling to have a proper implementation in java when it is required to have a set of constants values in String and those strings have the values again in integer/String.
for example,

1. small-diesel-car : 142g
2. small-petrol-car : 154g
3. small-plugin-hybrid-car : 73g
4. small-electric-car : 50g

So, I have defined those Strings literals in Constants.java like:

`public static final String SMALL_DIESEL_CAR = "small-diesel-car";`

But now "small-diesel-car" should have a value of 142.

My question is: How should I be handling this scenario using constants and enum classes or anything else?

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197988/java-enum-valueof-with-multiple-values 
You can ref to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4198066/2384806

Comment: Yes, It does answer. Thank you!