# Is it possible for class to implement the interface and execute logic behind that interface

Tags: java, class, interface

Good day developers.

So there is the problem:

I need my class `MyClass` implements the interface `IMyInterface` with method `doSomething();` and overrides method `doSomethiing()` the other class let's call him `TheOtherClass` also implements `IMyInterface`and overrides method `doSomethiing()` and plus  realize some logic of this `doSomething()` method(In `TheOtherClass`).

Question:

- How can I make `doSomething()` method implemented in `MyClass` trigger `doSomething()` from `TheOtherClass` automaticaly
- Also if `MyClass` invoked I want `doSomethig()` method invoke automaticaly??

Comment: You can derive from a common [class] implementation, or extract the "something" and use encapsulation.

Comment: I think constructor of `TheOtherClass` and `MyClass` is solution for *automatic trigger*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this.

```
public class TheOtherClass implements IMyInterface{
  public void doSomething(){}
}

public class MyClass implements IMyInterface{

// Instance initialization block:
// Runs before the constructor each time you instantiate an object
 {
   this.doSomething()
 }

  public MyClass(){
  }

  IMyInterface theOtherClass = new TheOtherClass ();

  public void doSomething(){
    theOtherClass .doSomething();
    //Add more logic here
  }
}
```

Instead of call doSomething in constructor as per this thread [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230565/can-i-call-methods-in-constructor-in-java) I suggest use the instance initialization blocks read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987428/what-is-an-initialization-block)

Comment: This is hardcoding anyway. I would prefer to add public class MyClass implements IMyInterface  to MyClass and only override doSomethig() this is it. Is it possible? I know I use Spring and ypu implement Interface with method and they will trigger automaticaly. Also my wishes

Comment: You never said something about spring XD, that change the context

Comment: I suggest then to use AOP to invoke operations on the case of certain methods or constructors are invoked. Please update your question with that or open a new one an select the correct one for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
1. make MyClass sub-class of TheOtherClass
2. call to super.doSumething() in MyClass's doSomething() method.
```

this will serve both of your purposes.
And b'coz it will be overriding you can change the logic in the method.
for details [click here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html)