# How to use methods with constructor in java?

Tags: java

I have some strange question.

I want to make constructor in java output some statements without using System.out inside the constructor itself.

This is my code:

```
public class NewClass1 {

public int view()
{
return 6;
}

public NewClass1()
{
    int a = view();
    System.out.println(a);
}

public static void main(String argv[])
{
    NewClass1 object = new NewClass1();
}

}
```

Now when i create object form that class it will output(6).

My question is: output 6 once the object is created but without using any outputs statements?

Comment: Your question is indeed strange. It is so strange that I do not get, what you are asking.

Comment: So, you want to write on the standard output without referring to it, don't you? That's a strange question, I agree.

Comment: Maybe you can explain better what a you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to output 6 without using any output statements inside the class or inside the constructor

Comment: How can you output something without using output statements? It makes no sense.

Comment: This answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230565/can-i-call-methods-in-constructor-in-java and gives an other way to let you run the code: static block.

Comment: You can step through the code with a debugger. That would allow you to see the values of variables without using `System.out`. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a class that handles only printing what you feed it like so

```
public class ConstructorPrinter {

    public void print(int a) {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

And then in your NewClass1 class you could use it in the following way

```
public class NewClass1 {
    ConstructorPrinter constructorPrinter = new ConstructorPrinter();

    public int view()
    {
        return 6;
    }

    public NewClass1()
    {
        constructorPrinter.print(view());
    }

    public static void main(String argv[])
    {
        NewClass1 object = new NewClass1();
    }
}
```

Comment: no, this is not my question. my question is that i want to output a value without using System.out inside the class or constructor.

Comment: @BeginnerProgrammer if you want to output something while you are in the constructor, you need to use `println(...)` within the constructor (at least if you want your code to stay somewhat simple).

Comment: @BeginnerProgrammer would an entirely new class that just prints whatever you feed it be what you're looking for then? If so, I can help you out with that

Comment: @BrandonLaidig not exactly what i am looking for but anyway post your answer to see :)

Comment: @BeginnerProgrammer I've updated my answer. Let me know

Comment: it's a good answer and +1 to it ...  but if i tell you that i don't need to use any output statements inside any classes or constructors, is this possible?  if impossible then your answer is the best one.

Comment: @BeginnerProgrammer to the best of my knowledge,  it's not possible to output without using an output

Comment: If you want to output something, at some point it has to go past output. You can put a lot of stuff in between, but is is like getting to an other country; it does not matter how long you make the road, or how weird the way you take is, at one point you will have to cross the border.