# Call non-static method from constructor in java

Tags: java, android, constructor

My question is about Java/Android.

How can I call a non-static method from an constructor?

My code:

```
public class input extends TextView{
    public input(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context, attr, getIdentifier()); //Error
    }
    
    public int getIdentifier(){
        if(getInputType() == InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS){
            return Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("editTextStyle","attr","android");
        }
        else{
            return Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("textViewStyle","attr","android");
        }
    }
}
```

I read all stackoverflow questions related to my question but no one helps me because they offer only two solution:
Create a new instance or
set the method to call to static

In this case, I can't create a new instance, because the app would crash:

```
super(context, attr, new input(context,attr).getIdentifier());//App crashes
```

And in my case, I can't set my getIdentifier method to static because then I can't call inside the getInputType method, as you can see...

So how can I solve my problem?

Comment: Cam you please show the constructor of `TextView`

Comment: Your requirement is to be able to call `getInputType()` at a time before the object is initialised. That's a bad idea. Depending on what `getInputType()` actually does, it is likely to return the wrong result.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230565/can-i-call-methods-in-constructor-in-java

Comment: make it static.

Comment: @MauricePerry I am going to go on a limp here and say that he can't because he is required to call `getInputType`. Unfortunately without sharing any more code, this is impossible to say for sure.

Comment: @akortex well this makes no sense because he cant call `getInputType` before the object was created.

Comment: @akortex there are the constructors of TextView: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/jb-mr0-release/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java

Comment: @MauricePerry, well technically he can. Assuming that `TextView` allows for setting the identifier at latter time, he can call `super` and then call `getIdentifier`. Design wise, this is bad and complicated but it is doable.

Comment: @akortex What code do you need?

Comment: @khelwood But I need to know the inputType to decide whether I show a TextView of an EditText...

Comment: As your question is about *non*-static methods, the tag [tag:static-methods] is irrelevant.

Comment: @khelwood And how would you solve this problem? Can I alternatively call super two times?

Comment: @user207421 I thought maybe there are a way to get the inputType from an static method...

Comment: If you must know that in order to construct your object, then you need to **figure it out in advance of calling the constructor**. You cannot decide it based on getting information from an uninitialised object; it just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @khelwood I already tried to "figure it out in advance of calling the constructor" but it didn't work. If doesn't make sense, can I alternatively call super two times? Or what would you do?

Comment: You cannot call super two times. If you tried to figure it out in advance and it didn't work, then you presumably have some code that you could post here and get help with. I don't know what `getInputType` does so I can't tell you how to solve it beyond what I've already said.

Comment: @khelwood I already posted here some code (above). With getInputType you get the type of the editable content. For example of you set in Edittext (xml) the following: android:inputType="textEmailAddress".