# Static classes and methods in coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

I want to write a static helper class in coffeescript. Is this possible?

class:

```
class Box2DUtility

  constructor: () ->

  drawWorld: (world, context) ->
```

using:

```
Box2DUtility.drawWorld(w,c);
```

Answer (score 179, accepted):

You can define class methods by prefixing them with `@`:

```
class Box2DUtility
  constructor: () ->
  @drawWorld: (world, context) -> alert 'World drawn!'

# And then draw your world...
Box2DUtility.drawWorld()
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/5yPh7/

And if you want your `drawWorld` to act like a constructor then you can say `new @` like this:

```
class Box2DUtility
  constructor: (s) -> @s = s
  m: () -> alert "instance method called: #{@s}"
  @drawWorld: (s) -> new @ s

Box2DUtility.drawWorld('pancakes').m()
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/bjPds/1/

Comment: Would `constructor: (@s) ->` also work in the second example? (i.e., instead of the manual assignment `@s = s`)

Comment: @TrippLilley: Yes, you could do it that way if you prefer.

Comment: But if we puts methods into 'this', they didn't be truly static anymore, isn't it? Truly static methods should stay in obj.prototype. In example of Shawn Mclean we may call methods like this: Box2DUtility::drawWorld(w,c);

Comment: @SergeyPanfilov: But anything in the prototype is also available through `this`, that's just how JavaScript works so you can't do anything about it. We don't really have classes either, just objects, prototypes, and constructor functions so the terminology is even more confused.  Attaching functions as properties of the constructor function (which is what's happening here) is the closest equivalent to a class method we have. Check the JavaScript `Box2DUtility::drawWorld`  won't work.

Comment: @SergeyPanfilov: Here's a simplified version of the structure [at coffeescript.org](http://coffeescript.org/#try:class%20C%0A%20%20im%3A%20-%3E%0A%20%20%40cm%3A%20-%3E%0A%0Aconsole.log%20C.cm%0Aconsole.log%20C%3A%3Acm).

Comment: Is there a way to execute `static blocks` in Coffeescript classes?

Comment: @AlvaroLourenço Sorry, not quite sure what you're asking.

Comment: Something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420389/static-initialization-blocks

Comment: @AlvaroLourenço Seems that a CoffeeScript class is a "static block" (with some extra stuff): https://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ap72ckax/

Comment: Maybe it's just me but I find this syntax very scary.
Might make sense if you stay in coffeescript world but it doesn't translate very well in JS.