# Overriding toString in CoffeeScript class

Tags: coffeescript

I've made a class in CoffeeScript and I'd like to overwrite the `toString()` function; here's my code:

```
class MenuController

  constructor: () ->
    'constructor'

  toString: () ->
    'MenuController'

console.log MenuController.toString()
```

However `toString()` returns:

```
function MenuController() {
  'constructor';
}
```

And not `MenuController`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Static classes and methods in coffeescript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090531/static-classes-and-methods-in-coffeescript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `toString` as a class method.  So, you can call it as:

```
menuController = new MenuController()
menuController.toString()
```

If a static method is really what you want, then you should use the following syntax:

```
class MenuController
  @toString: ->
    'MenuController'
```

Then, you'll be able to call it like:

```
MenuController.toString()
```

But, it will no longer be a class method, so

```
(new MenuController()).toString()
```

won't call your `toString` method.

Comment: Amazing! This is why I love SO!

Comment: Aren't a static method and class method the same thing? If you replace "class method" in this answer with "instance method", I think it would be correct.