# 2d array in Java returns null result

Tags: java, null, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to make an armour system for a text game using a 2D array in Java. I've got it all figured out in my head but the code doesn't seem to work.

```
public static String[][] armour = new String[2][3];
{
    armour[0][0] = "shirt";
    armour[0][1] = "plate";
    armour[0][2] = "iron";
    armour[1][0] = "1";
    armour[1][1] = "0.75";
    armour[1][2] = "0.5";
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(armour[0][1]);
}
```

This should return "plate" but it doesn't, and I have been looking it up, modifying it and all sorts for hours now and I cannot for the life of me figure it out. Does anybody here know?

Comment: I think you're confusing the `{}` block. That block is not linked to `armour` in any way.

Comment: Yeah, I'm fairly new to Java (well, programming in general) and I only leaned about 2d arrays ~2 days ago, so yeah. :)

Answer (score 5):

You are using an instance initializer block where you should have been using a static one.

```
public static String[][] armour = new String[2][3];
static {
    armour[0][0] = "shirt";
    armour[0][1] = "plate";
    armour[0][2] = "iron";
    armour[1][0] = "1";
    armour[1][1] = "0.75";
    armour[1][2] = "0.5";
}
```

Try this it will do the trick. You are not making an instance of your class and any block without the `static` keyword will only run if an instance is created.

Another option is using the array initializer block:

```
public static String[][] armour =
        {{"shirt", "plate", "iron"},{"1", "0.75", "0.5"}};
```

I have some remarks though:

- `public static` variables are asking for trouble. use `private` variables or constants (`public static final`)
- You should move the armour information to their separate class *OR* use a `Map` to store the key-value pairs: `shirt -> 1`

Comment: Yea, I extended my answer.

Comment: In the actual code, the armour info is in a class of it's own. This was just a little test class

Answer (score 1):

Create a static initializer:

```
static {
    armour[0][0] = "shirt";
    armour[0][1] = "plate";
    armour[0][2] = "iron";
    armour[1][0] = "1";
    armour[1][1] = "0.75";
    armour[1][2] = "0.5";
}
```

Otherwise, you will have to have a class instance in order to get the code block executed.

More info:

- [Static block vs. initializer block in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550135/static-block-vs-initializer-block-in-java)

Comment: Oh thanks! It worked :D I hate it when a massive problem boils down to missing one word.