# java - When is static {} called?

Tags: java, static, call

Take, for example, this class:

```
public class Example {
    static {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

When exactly is the static block called?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. I looked this up but for some reason I could not find anything.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550135/static-block-vs-initializer-block-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The static initializer block is called once, when the class is initialized. It is generally used to initialize static members of the class.

Answer (score 2):

The static initialization block is called when JVM load the class for the first time.