# Why is the code within empty braces getting executed first even before the constructor of the class?

Tags: java, inner-classes

Though this is a small question to ask, wanted to understand this strange behavior! Following is the code and the behavior of the code that's in discussion (through the console output).

```
public class EmptyBracesWithinClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EmptyBraces eb = new EmptyBraces();
        System.out.println("SYSO within main() method");
    }
}

class EmptyBraces {
    {
        System.out.println("SYSO within empty braces");
    }

    public EmptyBraces() {
        System.out.println("SYSO within constructor() method");
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
SYSO within empty braces
SYSO within constructor() method
SYSO within main() method
```

The question here is, why would the piece of code within the empty braces get executed first during the object instance creation of `EmptyBraces` class (though it is never declared as `STATIC` explicitly)?

Comment: Next time: do some prior research; and seriously; I don't get why people are upvoting an obvious duplicate ...

Comment: for some more info (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550135/static-block-vs-initializer-block-in-java)

Comment: Note: This is not a static initializer, but an instance initializer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`the piece of code within the empty braces` is called instance initializer block. It gets executed before the constructor body (and after the super class constructor is executed) whenever an instance of the class is created.

Answer (score 1):

This is because before print method excecuted of EmptyBracesWithinClass, you're calling EmptyBraces by instantiate it. so static initializer block run at first and then constructor will run.

Comment: you must read this first (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550135/static-block-vs-initializer-block-in-java)

Comment: thanks for your pointing. but i mean static initializer block exactly. i edit my answer, thanks again.