# Java static code block

Tags: java

Recently in a lot of programs I've been looking at, I've noticed

```
static {
    //some code here
}
```

I'm just looking for some information about this particularly, I'm used to blocks of code all being in methods, or simply classes, does this simply set all code within the block with a static modifier, or is there something more to it?

Comment: I guess you can consider it to be like a constructor, but for the class, not any instances of the class. Although I assume you can have multiple static blocks, but of course only one constructor per class.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This might be a duplicate question from
[Static Initialization Blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420389/static-initialization-blocks)

The static block only gets called once, no matter how many objects of that type you create.

Comment: Does JVM guarantee that the static block will be executed only once per application domain ?

Comment: The static block gets called each time the class is loaded. If there are multiple classloaders that load the class, the code gets executed multiple times.

Comment: if the program starts multiple times, the static block gets called multiple times also

Comment: Is it a possibility that the class never gets loaded and hence the method never gets called?

Answer (score 4):

The code inside a static block is executed first (e.g. before your constructor) once the JVM loads your class.

Comment: Would this code be inaccessible from external classes?

Comment: Here is the official explanation from Oracle http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

Answer (score 1):

Static blocks get called once (at a class level) and does not belong to a specific instance.

you can find more info (with good examples) [here](http://www.jusfortechies.com/java/core-java/static-blocks.php), or in the [official oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html).