# java web service retrieving empty list from class

Tags: java, web-services

this is my class whic I need to init 
there is a  static init on my class 
when I run the web method I am getting an exception

```
@WebService( serviceName = "SalesManager")

public class SalesManager {
       private static ServerListner serverLister;
       private static  Set<Client> clients;
       public static Set<Sale> sales;
       private static String status;
public SalesManager(){}
// this is the static block which should run once
static {
    ApplicationContext serverLoader = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("salesLoader.xml")
    clients  = new LinkedHashSet<Client>();
    sales = (Set<Sale>) serverLoader.getBean("sales");
    serverLister = (ServerListner) serverLoader.getBean("Serverlistner");
    status = "Created";  }
//this is the webmothod which I need to run
@WebMethod (operationName = "getOpenSales")
public Set<Sale>  getOpenSales (){
return SalesManager.sales; }
```

Comment: when I trying to retriev the data from web service I iam getting emppty list

Comment: You should edit the question and add more info in it.

Comment: Also, the web methods should contain the ways to access the data, not the Web Service constructor. If you want/need to load the `sales` attribute only once, make it `final static` and load it in a `static` code block.

Comment: how can grant access for my data to the webmethod?

Comment: Move the code from the constructor (that will never be called like that) to your `getOpenSales` method. If you only need to load the data once, use a [Static Initialization Block](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2420389/1065197).