# what does static { // some code } mean?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Static Initialization Blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420389/static-initialization-blocks)

What does the following mean in java?

```
static {                                        
  WritableComparator.define(IntPair.class, new Comparator());
}
```

Comment: The problem is that those who ask this question are not aware of that this thing is called a "static initializer block"

Comment: yes I have never heard of that until now.

Answer (score 9):

That means [static initialization block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) which will be executed on class load.

> If initialization requires some logic (for example, error handling or a for loop to fill a complex array), simple assignment is inadequate. Instance variables can be initialized in constructors, where error handling or other logic can be used. To provide the same capability for class variables, the Java programming language includes static initialization blocks.

Comment: read the link. it is explained there.

Comment: Java tutorial page about static: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

Comment: @MedicineMan: Add link to answer which explains more details and text which describes why we need it.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the code within that block will run once, when the type is loaded, before any constructors are called, but after any field initialisers are run.

Note that you cannot set any instance fields in the static block. There is no concept of `this` in there, just as in any other static methods.