# Statement surrounded by static { ... statement; } why, what for?

Tags: java, methods, static

For example I have following class

```
public class AnyClassName {

    static {

        AnyMethodCall(anyParameters, ..., ...);
    }

    body of class ...

}
```

The question is what is the reason of surrounding the method: **AnyMethodCall**(anyParameters, ..., ...) with **static { ... }** ?

Comment: That is a [static initializer block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420389/static-initialization-blocks) which allows to initialize static fields like some Map.

Comment: Thank you, now I understood, it calls  static initializer block, and its purpose is that statements inside static are executed only once! Thanks! )