# How to gain Static Constructor's functionality in JAVA?

Tags: java, constructor, static, static-constructor

I am learning C# and JAVA I found `Static Constructor` in C# which is used to initialize any static data, or to perform a particular action that needs to be performed once only. It is called automatically before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced.

For Example:

```css
class SimpleClass
{
    // Static variable that must be initialized at run time. 
    static readonly long baseline;

    // Static constructor is called at most one time, before any 
    // instance constructor is invoked or member is accessed. 
    static SimpleClass()
    {
        baseline = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    }
}
```

My Question is that how can I gain same functionality in JAVA is there any way ???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use static initialization block like this -

```
class SimpleClass
{
    static{

    }

}
```

The static block only gets called once, no matter how many objects of that type is being created.

You may see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420389/static-initialization-blocks) for more details.

**Update:** `static` initialization block is called only when the class is loaded into the memory.

Answer (score 7):

You have static initializer block.

```
static final long baseline;
static {
    baseline = ...
}
```

Comment: @BilalMaqsood It will be executed once when the class is initialized.