# Why does a Spring's FactoryBean getObject return null?

Tags: java, spring

I want to create a Spring `ConversionService` with custom `Converter`s, but the return value of `ConversionServiceFactoryBean#getObject` is `null`. See example:

```
@Bean
@Autowired
public ConversionService conversionService(Set<Converter<?, ?>> converters) {
    final ConversionServiceFactoryBean factory = new ConversionServiceFactoryBean();
    factory.setConverters(converters);
    return checkNotNull(
            factory.getObject(),
            "conversionService must not be null.");
}
```

`checkNotNull` throws a `NullPointerException`. The `converters` are injected as expected. Why does the factory return `null`? How can I fix that?

Comment: since you are using new keyword to create the factory bean and keeping it local , its not present in Spring context. Try creating a method (annotated with @Bean) returning factory bean and take it as parm to conversionService and then do getObject

Comment: Thanks, that's it! I've created a full answer to help others with same issue.

Comment: It's not because it's not in the Spring context. That's irrelevant. You can create and manage the instance yourself just fine. But you have to follow the requirements of the `FactoryBean` and `InitializingBean` interfaces and call `afterPropertiesSet` before `getObject`.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware of `afterPropertiesSet`. I hadn't expected this error-prone pattern, but now I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46364012/why-is-spring-conversionservice-null/46364314#comment79692260_46364012) of [Sotirios Delimanolis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438154/sotirios-delimanolis) I came to the following solution:

```
@Bean
public ConversionServiceFactoryBean conversionService(Set<Converter<?, ?>> converters) {
    final ConversionServiceFactoryBean factory = new ConversionServiceFactoryBean();
    factory.setConverters(converters);
    return factory;
}
```

This is essentially a shorthand for the following configuration:

```
@Bean
public ConversionService conversionService(Set<Converter<?, ?>> converters) {
    final ConversionServiceFactoryBean factory = new ConversionServiceFactoryBean();
    factory.setConverters(converters);
    factory.afterPropertiesSet(); // necessary
    return factory.getObject();
}
```

The factory remains in an unfinished state until `afterPropertiesSet` ([explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30726189/spring-why-is-afterpropertiesset-of-initializingbean-needed-when-there-are-st)) is called. However, one doesn't need to call it, if the `ConversionServiceFactoryBean` itself is returned instead of the `ConversionService`. Since the factory is a `InitializingBean` and a `FactoryBean` Spring will call `afterPropertiesSet` and `getObject` internally, if a ConversionService instance is needed.

Comment: The `ConversionServiceFactoryBean` is already producing a `ConversionService` bean, there's no need for another. Just pass the converters to the `ConversionServiceFactoryBean` and get rid of the `conversionService` `@Bean` method.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed and simplified the solution.

Comment: You can simplify it further. `ConversionServiceFactoryBean` is both a an `InitializingBean` and a `FactoryBean`. Both of those interface are special to Spring and part of a bean's lifecycle. Spring will invoke `afterPropertiesSet` and `getObject` for you if you register a bean of that type, putting the result in the application context as well. So the easiest way to do this would just be to instantiate `ConversionServiceFactoryBean`, set its converters, and return it. The rest is done by Spring.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've learned something fundamental today (worth a downvote ;-) ).