# Order of constructor calls in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, constructor-injection

I have a class `ServiceClass` annotated with `@Service`, inside that I do constructor injection for an object.

```
@Service
public class ServiceClass
{
    Dog dog;

    @Autowired
    public ServiceClass(Dog dog) {
        this.dog = dog;
    }
}
```

Now I also need to add some configuration code, that should run just once and prior to any other method call inside `ServiceClass`.

I thought of creating a no arg constructor and put those configuration inside those, but spring doesn't call that constructor.

Should I put it inside constructor where I do injection, or is there some other way to achieve it.

Comment: just call `this()` as first line of your constructor or include the configuration code in the constructor you have.

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple constructors (inside service class) performing constructor injection? In that case calling `this()` inside every constructor would result into issues.

Comment: "*Is it possible to have multiple constructors performing constructor injection?*" - By default, `@Service`s are singletons...

Comment: You can also use @PostConstruct in Spring

Comment: Thank you @CyrilG. Using `PostConstruct` better suits my needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are in this case two suitable options to go for without implementing the initialization logic in your constructor.

The First one is an @PostConstruct where you define your configuration logic. Another option would be to let your ServiceClass implement the InitializingBean interface and put this configuration logic in your afterPropertiesSet method.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning InitializingBean. Any future reader may also want to read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/30726748/13866126