# When objects created with static reference, why do instance block & default constructor get executed before static block?

Tags: java, static-block

```
public class TestLab {

    static Test aStatic=new Test();
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TestLab obj=new TestLab();
    }
    static{
        System.out.println("In static block of TestLab");
          }

}


public class Test {


    static Test ref=new Test();
    Test()
    {
        System.out.println("Default Constructor of Test");
    }
    static
    {
        System.out.println("In Static Block of Test");
    }
    {
         System.out.println("In instance block of Test");
    }

}
```

Normally the static blocks are executed first during class loading. When the above example is executed, the following output is received:

> In instance block of Test
>
> Default Constructor of Test
>
> In Static Block of Test
>
> In instance block of Test
>
> Default Constructor of Test
>
> In static block of TestLab

Why does the instance block and Default Constructor of Test class gets executed before the static block of Test Class?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420389/static-initialization-blocks

Comment: @Arunachalam: That doesn't answer this question at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok. `static` fields / blocks are set / executed during class initialization. *They are executed in the order that they appear* in the code.
So, after class `TestLab` is loaded, when it is getting initialized, the following things happen :

1. `static Test aStatic=new Test();` ==>
   Called as part of initialization of class `TestLab`. From here, `Test` class is referenced. So, control moves to `Test` class.
2. `static Test ref=new Test();` ==> i.e, first line of Test class (during its initialization phase) is executed. This line involves creating a new instance of `Test`, so control moves to instance block (**In instance block of Test**)  of `Test` and then to constructor (**Default Constructor of Test**).
3. Now `static Test ref=new Test();` is complete, so, the class initialization of `Test` continues and reaches the static block (**In Static Block of Test**). This completes initialization of `Test`.
4. Control reaches back to `TestLab`, now `new Test()` is called. So again **In instance block of Test** and **Default Constructor of Test** are printed (class is already initialized, so `static` fields are not initialized again and static blocks are not executed).
5. Control reaches static block of `TestLab` (**In static block of TestLab**).

Comment: I got the order, but wont the static blocks of TestLab and Test be executed before executing any instance blocks or calling the constructor. I mean, the static block is called when the class is loaded. Isn't the TestLab class loaded before executing **static Test aStatic =new Test();** and isn't the Test class loaded before executing ** static Test ref=new Test();**

Comment: @ArijitDasgupta - Class initialization happens after class loading. static initializers are run during class initialization. instance blocks / constructors of `Test` are getting executed during *initialization* of the class i.e, as part of that process.

Answer (score 1):

When the type is initialized, all the static initializers *and all the static field initializers* are executed, in textual order. From [JLS 12.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2):

> Next, execute either the class variable initializers and static initializers of the class, or the field initializers of the interface, in textual order, as though they were a single block.

In other words, this code gets executed:

```
ref = new Test();
System.out.println("In Static Block of Test");
```

That first line creates an instance... which requires the instance initializer to be run. All of that instance initialization happens before control returns to the type initialization part - i.e. before the line from the static initializer runs.

If you move the field declaration to *after* the static initializer, you'll see the opposite results.

Answer (score 0):

Usually `static variables/blocks` will be initialized in the order they are defined, here you have marked `aStatic` as `static`. It will try to create the instance of Test by invoking constructor, but as instance block is provided it will get executed and then the constructor and eventually the static block.