# Is it bad form to declare constants using methods?

Tags: java, constants

I did a search and could not find any other threads that cover this specific topic.

```
    public static final Path DIR  = ROOT.resolve(NAME);
```

Is there any reason this would be considered bad practice?

Comment: Nothing specific, as that's a field value and field values are initialized first there shouldn't be issue with that code. But maybe you should consider using static initialization block for that.

Comment: Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2420405/544779

Comment: I see. Thank you for your answer. Maybe this will help anyone else who is wondering whether static final variables assigned through a method are good practice or not.

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is the tight coupling between the class having this constant and what ever the type of `ROOT` is.

So if `DIR` is something that is not known at compile time it should be *injected* into the class (preferably as a constructor parameter) and held in a `private final` (but not <strike>`static`</strike>) member.

Comment: The purpose is just to ensure that the path is uniformly used throughout the class as well as other classes having access to this path. I originally had a getter method but then I started asking myself why and then I came up with this. It compiles fine sure but it doesn't feel right as it feels wrong to instantiate a class with something that has the potential to return null (possibility, though unlikely). You are probably right though. The constructor is private anyways so initializing in a constructor or a static initialization block as other have said probably makes more sense. Thank you :P

Answer (score 1):

What you did, is a declaration of a global variable. It is bad practice itself. What I would rather suggest is to declare this variable as private and initialize it in a constructor of class that will be granted only responsibility to operate on that directory (?). Consider a situation when the directory path calculation method would change. It would impact all other classes that use this variable. So it would be better to limit any negative impacts.

Comment: Yes, the files this class is responsible for only exist in a single directory. Root is where the program was ran. Not system root such as C:\