# Unpredictable behaviour of an initializer block

Tags: java

```
public class Ex14 {
    static String strDef = "At the point of definition";
    static String strBlock;
    { strBlock = "In a block";}

    public static void main (String [] args){       
        System.out.println(Ex14.strDef);
        System.out.println(Ex14.strBlock);
        Ex14 test = new Ex14();
        System.out.println(test.strBlock);
        System.out.println(Ex14.strBlock);
    }

}
```

Result:

```
$ java Ex14
At the point of definition
null
In a block
In a block
```

If I switch the block with the commented one, both statements are printed. In other words, I just

Well, I can't catch what is going on here.

Questions:

1. Inside the initializer block the variable is non-static. If it is
   not anyhow mixed with that static declaration, why the compiler
   didn't even warn me?
2. When an instance was created, strBlock is not null anymore. I can't
       catch why?
3. Anyway, I can't understand anything here. Please, could you clarify
       it somehow?

Comment: `"In a static block"` is **not** in a `static` block since the block is missing the `static` keyword.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Static Initialization Blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420389/static-initialization-blocks)

Comment: Ok. You are right. The block had been initially declared as static, but for learning purpose I removed this word. Anyway, the question is still actual.

Comment: Can you change the code to match the question? For example: "Inside the initializer block the variable is non-static." No, the variable is static

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: Very interesting question. Never saw that. Ok, I would never write this, but very interesting.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Inside the initializer block the variable is non-static. If it is not anyhow mixed with that static declaration, why the compiler didn't even warn me?

No, the variable is still `static`. You're just assigning a new value to the static variable.

> 2. When an instance was created, strBlock is not null anymore. I can't catch why?

Instance initializers are inlined into the constructor, in between an (implicit or explicit) call to `super(...)` and the rest of the body. What you have here is equivalent to:

```
public class Ex14 {
    static String strDef = "At the point of definition";
    static String strBlock;

    public Ex14() {  // Default constructor.
      super(); // Implicit super constructor invocation.

      // Inlined instance initializer.
      Ex14.strBlock = "In a block";

      // Rest of the constructor body (there is none for a default ctor).
    }

    public static void main (String [] args){ 
      // ...
    }
 }
```

So, before you create an instance, the `Ex14.strBlock = "In a block";` statement hasn't executed, so its value is `null`; after you create an instance (and hence execute the constructor), `Ex14.strBlock` has been reassigned.