# How to load a property file just once and use it throughout the application in java?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I have a scenario where i need to show the success/error messages in jsp's from the controller. The controller has access to many methods and each method may return some message. These messages are stored as key-value pair in a property file which i need to access. Now i want to load this property file just once and use it through out the application. How can this be achieved? the framework is spring mvc. Presently i am doing something like this in every class but this approach doesn't seem right. Please help!

```
Properties prop = new Properties(); 
prop.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName+".properties"));
```

Comment: how about a static singleton class that holds this data

Comment: Can u give an example? what should be the appraoch?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750131/make-java-properties-available-across-classes

Comment: singleton is not correct approach here, using spring mvc one can load the properties.

Comment: @Shivayan, did you get the solution from the answers?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is probably what is described in [this](http://kh-yiu.blogspot.gr/2013/08/spring-injecting-properties-file-values.html) blog post.

In short, here is what you have to do:

First tell spring where the properties file in your spring configuration.
That will look something like:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"/>
```

Second you inject the properties into Spring beans with the [@Value](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html?is-external=true) annotation

Answer (score 0):

you can load the properties file using spring configurations as below:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"/>
```

Add the above configuration in the spring beans configuration file and put the properties file under the source folder which are by default in the classpath.

@Value annotation can be used for injecting the property values at your controller. Something like this:

```
@Value("${name}")
private String name;
```

your properties file entries would look like this:
`enter code here`name=your name

I hope this explanation would solve your problems.